# regex to match number followed by space followed by 2 char

Tags: python, regex

I have a requirement in my python app to match 2 to 7 digit number followed by a string with 2 chars in caps.

Examples - 6892 NY, 12382 OP

If these pattern appear anywhere in a line of text, need to add the two words(number and 2 chars) as one string to a list. Any insights how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help `r"\b\d{2,7}\s+[A-Z]{2}\b"`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "6892 NY, 12382 OP"
print( re.findall(r"\b\d{2,7}\s+[A-Z]{2}\b", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['6892 NY', '12382 OP']
```

- `\d{2,7}`  number followed by 2 to 7 digits
- `\s+`      for space
- `[A-Z]{2}` for Uppercase 2 letters

Comment: for numbers with more than 7 digits and words with more than 2 letters, if substring matches are not allowed, can be surrounded by `(?<!\d)` .. `(?![A-Z])`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul. That's true. But OP has specifically asked to match 2-7 digits and 2 Capital letters.